# Different default keyboard layouts for different applications

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, default-settings

I know that it is possible in Windows 10 to switch between keyboard language layouts only for the active application but my question would be about how to make these choices to be default.

I mean, when I open for example the Cygwin terminal, I always get a Hungarian keyboard layout and have to switch to English manually. Is it possible to make the English layout to be default for Cygwin (or any other layout for any other application, in general)?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Zsolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to deal with the problem using AutoHotKey, which will automatically assign a default keyboard to all apps, except specific ones (e.g. Cygwin)

This script will not loop; it will get notified when switching to another window.

https://gist.github.com/christianrondeau/00d7cd5848f33e029f00ce2b6b935ab9

```
; How to use:
; 1. Install AuthotKey: https://www.autohotkey.com
; 2. Save this script in `My Documents`
; 3. Create a shortcut in the Startup folder (`Win`+`R`, `shell:startup`)
; 4. Change the configurations below
; 5. Start and test the script!

; Configuration

    ; Cultures can be fetched from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx
    ; They must be set twice in the language ID;
    ;   en-US: 0x04090409
    ;   fr-CA: 0x0C0C0C0C

global DefaultLanguage := "fr-CA"
global DefaultLanguageIndentifier := "0x0C0C0C0C"
global SecondaryLanguage := "en-US"
global SecondaryLanguageIndentifier := "0x04090409"
global SecondaryLanguageWindowTitles := "VIM,Visual Studio"

; And the code itself (you should not have to change this)

Gui +LastFound 
hWnd := WinExist()
DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,Hwnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam )
{
 WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %lParam%
; 4 is HSHELL_WINDOWACTIVATED, 32772 is HSHELL_RUDEAPPACTIVATED
 If (wParam=4 || wParam=32772) {
    If title contains %SecondaryLanguageWindowTitles%
        SetKeyboard( title, SecondaryLanguage )
    Else
        SetKeyboard( title, DefaultLanguage )
 }
}

SetKeyboard( title, culture )
{
    ; 0x50 is WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST.
    Try
    {
        If (culture = SecondaryLanguage)
        {
            PostMessage, 0x50, 0, %SecondaryLanguageIndentifier%,, A
            ; To debug:
            ; ToolTip, Using secondary language %SecondaryLanguage%
            ; Sleep 1000
            ; ToolTip
        }
        Else If (culture = DefaultLanguage)
        {
            PostMessage, 0x50, 0, %DefaultLanguageIndentifier%,, A
            ; To debug:
            ; ToolTip, Using default language %DefaultLanguage%
            ; Sleep 1000
            ; ToolTip
        }
        Else
        {
            ; To debug:
            ; ToolTip, Unknown culture: %culture%
            ; Sleep 1000
            ; ToolTip
        }
    }
    Catch e
    {
        ToolTip, Could not switch to %culture%`n%e%
        Sleep 1000
        ToolTip
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and I'd like to apologize for answering after so much time. Will try your soluiton as soon as possible! :)

Comment: No problem, hope it works for you. Keep in mind that if you are in a program that "run as administrator", unless AutoHotKey also runs as administrator, the language will not change.

Comment: Just tried it and works beautifully with Notepad++, or RStudio, but Cygwin might be just an example for issues you mentioned in your previous comment. Read after the problem and found [this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/). Despite I completed the instructions nothing changed - doesn't matter how I give the name of Cygwin in the script (_cygwin_, _Cygwin64_, _mintty_, etc.), the language isn't changed when the app started). Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Hey @ZsoltLászló - sorry, I stopped using cygwin, so I can't say. The link you shared would have been my suggestion, otherwise my two theories are A) the actual cygwin (mintty?) window does not receive  the keyboard events, it's parent does (just a theory), and B) something in cygwin processes keys differently, so they do not reach Windows... Not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will check it in the upcoming days and share the experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) you can periodically check for active window and switch the keyboard layout based on the window which became active.

Let me quote similar solution which switches keyboard layout to English when Total Commander's QuickSearch window becomes active. I guess that if you understand tools like cygwin, you should be easily able to adjust this one for your needs.

Readability hint: In script listings below, semicolon starts a comment till end of line.

http://www.script-coding.com/AutoHotkey/AhkRussianEng.html

> At first, we create a timer that will launch automation of windows,
>   and insert it somewhere into the auto-executing section of a script.

```
#Persistent ; The script will be persistent
;(if you have any hotkeys or hotstrings after the auto-execution section,
;this directive is unnecessary)
SetTimer, Auto_Window, 200 ; Move to the specified subroutine every 0.2 seconds
Return ; Finish the auto-executing part
```

> Now the subroutine of automation of windows itself:

```
Auto_Window:
;a label to call the window automation timer (this subroutine can be placed
;at any place of the script. I like to put subroutines at the end of a script, but it is not compulsory)

; switch the keyobard layout if QuickSearch window is active
IfWinActive, ahk_class TQUICKSEARCH ; if the quick search window in TC is active, then...
{
    if Win_QS = ; if the window has just become active, then...
    {
        SendMessage, 0x50,, 0x4090409,, ahk_class TQUICKSEARCH
        ; Switch the layout to English in the quick search window
        Win_QS = 1 ; Flag that the window is already active 
    }
}
Else ; if the window is not active, then...
    Win_QS = ; Flag that the window is NOT active

Return ; The end of the subroutine that is called by the timer
```

Refer to [documentation for IfWinActive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) to learn how to recognize windows of your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and I'd like to apologize for answering after so much time. Will try your soluiton as soon as possible! :)